# Enable the controls in a InfoPath 2010 read-only view

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

Hi 
I would like to display a read-only infopath form the the end-users.I have created a read-only view,everything works perfectly apart from the file attachments.In a a read-only infopath form view , users could not download the file attachments.Is there a way I could ovverride this just for the file attachment?Otherwise ,I have to create a rule to manually make every controls read-only on the form.
Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the drawbacks to a "read only" view. I have not found a way around it easily. My alternative is to create the view as non read only but make all the controls read only during design. You don't have to use a rule - just check the box for each one. Yes it is a pain but you only have to do it one time during design (and remember if you add any new fields to make them read only as well). I also shade the text boxes so users don't get confused and think they can edit, and convert dropdowns to text boxes/labels, etc. Much easier to view and print that way. If you make a file attachment control read only directly on the control a user can save or open but not remove or overwrite.