# How to make sure users can only download file from the attachment control but not be able to upload or remove it

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I'd like to create a read-only view in the infopath.However when I disable the attachment control ,user can not download the file at all.How to make sure users can only download file from the attachment control but not be able to upload or remove it.

Comment: This is technically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610222/enable-the-controls-in-a-infopath-2010-read-only-view Please combine them in order to keep only a single Q/A trail going.

Comment: It's close, but I don't want to "enable the controls in a read-only view" as per the other post. I want to just make the Attachment control read-only. So I've voted this one back-up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are customizing a SharePoint List form, you will not be able to set the File Attachment control to read only.  However, I was able to work around this, and this will work for you even if it's just a regular form, by using repeating sections with hyperlink controls inside.

- In the Fields pane, click on Show Advanced View
- Expand Attachments so you can see the attachmentURL field
- Drag attachmentURL into the form and choose Repeating Section with Controls
- Click in the section and press CTRL-K to insert a Hyperlink
- Enter . in Data Source for Link to
- Enter . in Data Source for Display

There are some gotchas and workarounds for some problems you may encounter.  See more details on my blog post http://vincepangan.com/?p=220

Answer (score -1):

context menu -> Properties, there is a check box (the first one) on the first tab, make sure it is not checked.

EDIT: If your **view** is read-only, you cannot download the attachment. The workaround is to clear the read-only checkbox of the *view*, and activate the read-only on all other controls. The attachment control can be configured to not allow upload/modification of the attachment. This means that in order to upload or modify an attachment, you'll need an other view.

See also entries on msdn:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointinfopath/thread/1106f090-7767-431f-a699-b81c1173c2ee
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/36c07bd7-a5ba-4fa0-b992-e9a94103dbf4
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/sharepoint2010customization/thread/412e80ce-badb-4467-a2d1-7e1696774058

Comment: Then I could not download it either.